# /setblock command in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In my minecraft world (in 1.13), I need to /setblock blue stained glass, which I believe has the ID `3`. (FYI, I use the tilde symbol (~) in place of the coordinates because they are not really very important regarding my question.)

In 1.12, I was able to use:
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stained_glass 3`.

In 1.13, I tried:
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:glass 3`, but it didn’t seem to work.

How will I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`blue_stained_glass` now has its own ID, like so:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ blue_stained_glass
```

---

In 1.13, item damage values are only used for actual damage (like on tools/armor), so you'll also notice changes like `bonemeal` rather than `dye 15`, or `charcoal` rather than `coal 1`.

Then, block IDs correspond to item IDs, and **blockstates** (numeric block metadata no longer exists) are only used for properties like rotation/powered/open that a block placed by that item can have.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ dispenser[facing=up]
```

Comment: Hi, @SirBenet, in your answer you mentioned: “dispenser[facing=up]. Is it [facing=up] or dispenser 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: @user209814 `dispenser[facing=up]` - blockstates are specified like that (square brackets, after bock name) in 1.13, and numeric metadata no longer exists.

Comment: Really, @SirBenet? I thought for buttons you could do like (Example: /testforbock lever 12.

Comment: And actually I did and it worked so maybe can you do it for levers and buttons but not blocks?

Comment: You need to use blockstates (e.g: `[facing=up]`) now, numeric metadata no longer exists for any blocks as of 1.13.